# Sometimes, I cannot fetch string from resource in Android?

Tags: android, xml, resources

I found this problem on ASUS fonepad(android version 4.1.2) not on zendfone 3.

(Two devices I only have)

It function normally when I just open my app.

Once I let it idle too long, some of the text would be blank.

--

e.q.:

1.
http://ppt.cc/jcsi

This page should full of text in each block.

2.http://ppt.cc/PY67

There should be some text shown in the blank area.

--

I saved all of the text in the xml file.

Therefore, I think this should be the problem of resource?

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

----code----

```
/* I use this function for creating textview  */
protected TextView customizeTextView(String text,float textSize, int bgc, int gravity,int textcolor)
{
    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setTextSize(textSize);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(bgc);
    tv.setGravity(gravity);
    tv.setTextColor(textcolor);

    return tv;
}

/*The parameter of string should be getString(R.string.stopDectecting); or logObject.recordId+"" */
```

Comment: post the code which you are using to fetch string from resource.

Comment: I had edited my post.

Comment: Did you use different xml for landscape and portrait?  And also is your app is work with landscape and portrait or any one?

Comment: @Ray: I doubt your TextView is being garbage collected by Android OS that is why it is showing blank. Your code is very abstract piece. Add more details.

Comment: Code is still totally incomplete. I'd suggest you post more code. In your customizeTextView method, just print to LogCat to see if the String is properly loaded.

Comment: Yes idling might destroy your Activity/Views, this is usually no problem when the View was set using a XML file and all TextViews have a unique Id.
Here my wild guess: because you generate the TextViews by code and don't assign a unique id to the views, the state is not retained in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: I force the app SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT and there is only two xml files because of language issue.

Comment: Even there is different activity? I had test this by changing the activity. However, if this problem happened in A activity, it would occur on other activity.

Comment: Also, I found that it seems not happend on zendfone 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `tv.setText(text);` with `tv.setText(R.string.MY_STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer finally.

At first, my app would calculate the ratio of current screen verse 800*480.

But with low possibility, it would get the 0 value.

This is only happened one ASUS fonepad.

Therefore, I change the time of calculation the ratio and it solved.